# configure material-ui on asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, material-ui, material-design

I want to run material-design on my asp.net core project.
in visual studio 2019  [image: first I add Client-side Library as you see]

[image: after I installed it these folders came up]

but how should I use them in my project
the sample code for side bar drawer is this.

```
  <aside class="mdc-drawer">
  <div class="mdc-drawer__content">
    <nav class="mdc-list">
      <a class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--activated" href="#" aria-current="page">
        <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">inbox</i>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Inbox</span>
      </a>
      <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
        <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">send</i>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Outgoing</span>
      </a>
      <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
        <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">drafts</i>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Drafts</span>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</aside>
```

can anyone help how to call material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this github about Material Components for the web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web) , you could try the following code ,not add the client-side library

```
<aside class="mdc-drawer">
<div class="mdc-drawer__content">
    <nav class="mdc-list">
        <a class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--activated" href="#" aria-current="page">
            <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">inbox</i>
            <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Inbox</span>
        </a>
        <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
            <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">send</i>
            <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Outgoing</span>
        </a>
        <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
            <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">drafts</i>
            <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Drafts</span>
        </a>
    </nav>
</div>
</aside>

@section Scripts
{
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
  <!-- Required MDC Web JavaScript library -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    mdc.drawer.MDCDrawer.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-drawer'));
    mdc.list.MDCList.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-list'));
  </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]